# How to get texi2pdf to stop on the first error (again)?

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error, texi2dvi

I use `texi2pdf` (GNU Texinfo 6.7 (2019); on macOS) to compile `.tex` documents from the command line (terminal).
A couple of years ago, the default was that `texi2pdf` stopped at the first error. For some reason, this
must have changed. Now the behavior is that `texi2pdf` runs 'nonstop' and, in case of errors,
puts out `"/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting."`. This
one line is easily overlooked and then you need to scroll back in the terminal to actually see
the errors (like `Missing $ inserted`, for example). Run the below MWE with `texi2pdf MWE.tex` to see that
(unless you perhaps have the extremely old `texi2dvi` version from 2003 or so that used to ship with macs).
The version of `texi2dvi` I have is precisely the one from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/texi2dvi).
How can I get `texi2dvi` to stop on the first error (so at `Missing $ inserted`) like `pdflatex` does?

Judging from [this post](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2003-August/000748.html), there used to be an option `nonstopmode`,
but that's not available anymore it seems. Interestingly, this makes sense with what I experienced some years ago
where the `stopmode` was the default so-to-say and one needed to actively ask for `nonstopmode` if necessary.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
These_underscores_lead_to_errors_but_texi2pdf_wont_stop_at_the_first_error_so_you_need_to_scroll_to_find_it
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to change the source code of `texi2dvi` then you can modify the line where the LaTeX command is constructed.

The original source (from line 888 onwards):

```sh
# Run without interaction.
# \batchmode does not show terminal output at all, so we don't
# want that.  And even in batch mode, TeX insists on having input
# from the user.  Close its stdin to make it impossible.
tex_cmd="$tex_cmd </dev/null '${escape}nonstopmode'"
```

Change `nonstopmode` into `errorstopmode`. Now `texi2dvi` will still run multiple times, but each time it will halt on the first error, so you will see the error at the end of the terminal output instead of somewhere in the middle.

Comment: It would be great if this was an option of `texi2dvi`.

Comment: @MariusHofert that would be useful indeed. According to the Texinfo project page you can send bug reports and feature requests to bug-texinfo@gnu.org. There is also an issue tracker (http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=texinfo) but that doesn't seem to be very active.

Comment: I now sent a feature request.